# dataGridView not showing database records

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datagridview

I've tried many different methods but really can't seem to find a solution to this confusing problem.

Code:

```
public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //connection class
    connection cc = new connection();

    //displaying current office employees
    public void display()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cc.connectDB());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" select USERID, NAME, INLATE from USERINFO", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader c = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        table.Columns.Add("USERID", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("INLATE", typeof(string));
        while (true)
        {
            if (c.Read() == true)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(c.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim(), c.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim(), c.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim());
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
```

This is a simple application build that requires data to be on display within the dataGridView object.

Please save me somebody.

Comment: Do you get any error or exception message?

Comment: nope, nothing. I build the app then it runs but doesn't seem to display any data within the area it should.

Comment: What is the problem with above code... what is Result....

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource = table;dataGridView1.DataBind(); may solves your problem

Comment: I'm simply shown a blank dataGridView object with simply no error dialogue displayed to notify me of the issue...

Comment: I worked out the answer in the end, it was a simple issue with the coding on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the actual server name and credentials enabled me to call the queries with accessible feedback, thanks for all your help people...

Answer (score 1):

Hehe, you are unlucky in your selection of Query. ExecuteNonQuery will never bring back any results. It is what you use when you run UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE. Now when you want to read the values you need to execute a reader.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" select USERID, NAME, INLATE from USERINFO", con);
SqlDataReader c = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but unfortunately this isn't the case as I just tried this also :(

Comment: @SonerGönül haha wops. I keep switching between the two tags so I dont even reflect on what type of code I am reading :P

Comment: Now it's changed to C#

Comment: Didn't work for me :( thanks for your help though! Is there anyway I'm able to at least show the database table "USERINFO" fully without defining the columns and rows just so I have a good foundation to start from?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/353481/How-can-we-fill-data-table-in-sqlcommand I guess this would do that.

Answer (score 0):

To get sure that the query fetch u any ressults (in case you don't have access from any database client e.g Management Stydio)
Try:

```
List <string> l1=new List <string>();

         SqlDataReader c = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (c.Read())
        {
           l1.Add(c[0].ToString());
        }
     c.CLose();
     con.CLose();
     Messabox.Show(li.Count.ToString());
     return;
     dataGridView1.DataSource = table.AsDataView();
```

from there you will have a starting point to get to figure out if the problem is in the query or in the way you bind the data in the datatable